# Concatenate multiple strongly typed HTML Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

The code in my razor view (MVC 5) is being repeated with the following pattern such as FirstName, LastName, ShortName, etc. Am wondering is it possible to encapsulate to a single HTML Helper which can accept strongly typed lambda expression and generate the following HTML for me?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "validate" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
<span class="red-text">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</span>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "validate" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
<span class="red-text">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
</span>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName, new { @class = "validate" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShortName)
<span class="red-text">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ShortName)
</span>
```

Ideally, I would like to write:

```
@Html.DisplayTextBox(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayTextBox(m => m.LastName)
@Html.DisplayTextBox(m => m.ShortName)
```

I think, this is possible to achieve but I don't know how? I hope someone can help me or point me to the resource where I can read up and write the code?

I don't want to be dependent on EditorTemplate, because I want to control the form format.

Comment: Yes, can create your own HtmlHelper extension method to output whatever html you want

Comment: Yes - I know this should be possible. Am a beginner in MVC, can you please give me some reference to start with?

Comment: Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own HtmlHelper extension methods to generate the combined output. The following will create the html your after

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourAssembly.Html
{
  public static class MyHelpers
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {      
      MvcHtmlString label = LabelExtensions.LabelFor(helper, expression);
      MvcHtmlString textbox = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression, new { @class = "validate" });
      MvcHtmlString validation = ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor(helper, expression);
      StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
      html.Append(textbox);
      html.Append(label);
      TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
      span.AddCssClass("red-text");
      span.InnerHtml = validation.ToString();
      html.Append(span.ToString());
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Then your can make it available in all you views by adding it to web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      ....
      <add namespace="YourAssembly.Html" />
    </namespaces>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I tried the similar code earlier from some article but that didn't work, it's because the Func<> is mentioned in System and Antlr.Runtime.Misc, so the error it gave ambiguity! Using your snippet, I did manage to figure that out and removed the reference to "Antlr.Runtime.Misc".

Thought, it's worth to mention, it may help others. Thanks Stephen!

Comment: Lovely.  This is just what I've been searching for.

Unlikely to get a reply I know, but is there anyway to include overrides on the text for these?  I am using a CMS so all of my forms have user input values for labels and errors.  So, I'd be using:

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName, "Some user entered error message")

Can this be done?

Comment: @TonyKiernan. Sure, You would just include additional parameters in the method for them

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  But when I tried

public static MvcHtmlString DisplayTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string myAlert)

myAlert was always empty, even when I hard coded a value.

Comment: @TonyKiernan, It would work fine. Without seeing your code I cant tell what you might be wrong, so suggest you ask a new question with the details

Comment: OK, thanks.  Will do that.  Hopefully I'll get a chance to look at it again this week